# access oauth token to secure my standalone struts framework application

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I have an oauth-2 authorisation server already hosted. I send `http://**.***.**.**:9999/security/version1/login` with json params

```
{
  "grant_type":"password",
  "username":"admin",
  "password":"admin",
  "client_id":"MyOauth2Client",
  "client_secret":"KKJKJKJ9kWEEW]2s]fdhdsP"
}
```

and I can get the response

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "MDI4NTQ0ZTEtZDBhZC00MjgyLWJkNDQtNzQxZjNhMjY4YWY0",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "OTFjODViMTQtMDljYi00NTYyLWIwMjEtNTcxY2U0ZGU0OWRj"
}
```

How can I use these `access_token` and `refresh_token` to protect my secured API which is hosted as stand-alone restful service? I have security intercept method before every API call. So how can I implement the access token and refresh token so as to protect the API's?

Comment: Not answering, but the question should not contains sensitive data, I think you should change the secret keys (generate a new one), it is not correct to share them, edit question will not hide remove them because you will still can see them in edit history.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the client secret is already the edited one . lol